# Save multiple selection of dropdown list to variables using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, variables, drop-down-menu, save

I have there dropdown lists with values, and one textarea to write those valuse in. When i press button it writes values of all three selected dropdown lists, it do that every time when i press the button (it do it three times). This pice of code writes values of dropodown lists, like this:
Button pressed first time: "Conntent of dropdown lists" undefinedundefined
Button pressed second time: undefined"Conntent of dropdown lists"undefined
Button pressed third time: undefinedundefined"Conntent of dropdown lists"

But i want values of dropdown list not "undefined"

What can you think of?

```
var i = 0;
function inc(){
i++;

if (i == 1){
var UkupnaPorudzbina1 = VrsteName + ' -> ' + PodvrsteName + ' -> ' + VelicineName + i;
}else if (i == 2){
var UkupnaPorudzbina2 = VrsteName + ' -> ' + PodvrsteName + ' -> ' + VelicineName + i;
}else if (i == 3){
var UkupnaPorudzbina3 = VrsteName + ' -> ' + PodvrsteName + ' -> ' + VelicineName + i;
}
var porudzba = UkupnaPorudzbina1 + UkupnaPorudzbina2 + UkupnaPorudzbina3;
    document.frmMain.PorudzbaHolder.value = porudzba ;
}
```

VrsteName is:

```
VrsteName = document.frmMain.Vrste.options[document.frmMain.Vrste.selectedIndex].text
```

PodvrsteName and VelicinaName are same sort

And html part is:

```
<textarea name="PorudzbaHolder" rows="4"> </textarea>
<input type="button" value="Dodaj porudzbinu" onClick="inc();"/>
```

Thx in advance...

Comment: You could at least shorten your variables so code would fit in easier (but that's just my opinion). :)

Comment: @Robert Koritnik, it fits in my widescreen :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are declaring only one of the three variables each time, but then referencing all three later.  Try declaring your variables first and initializing them to `""`:

```
var UkupnaPorudzbina1 = "";
var UkupnaPorudzbina2 = "";
var UkupnaPorudzbina3 = "";
```

Then run the rest of your code as written, but leaving the `var` out before each assignment to `UkupnaPorudzbina`.